# show an element when it comes to the layer

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make an element div visible when it comes to the right div.

This is the code for what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/wjewq5yq/1/

So when the white `<div id="block2"></div>` is on the `<div id="content"></div>`, it must be hidden, but as long as enters to `<div id="block1"></div>`, the white element must be revealed.

Any idea of how could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is only about plain colors, then, you may set  the blue one transparent and paint the green around it via `box-shadow`, add some `relative` and `z-index` to finalize it:

```css
#content {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#block1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 500px green, inset 1px 1px 3px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}
#block2 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    -webkit-animation: moveDiv 5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: moveDiv 5s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: moveDiv 5s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: moveDiv 5s linear infinite 0s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDiv {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-150px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes moveDiv {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    25% {
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    50% {
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100px);
    }
    75% {
        -ms-transform: translateX(-150px);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: translateX(-300px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveDiv {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    25% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    50% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
    }
    75% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-150px);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-300px);
    }
}
@keyframes moveDiv {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-100px);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateX(-150px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-300px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
```

if it is about graphic backgrounds (image/texture), then the white element should not be aside the blue and direct child of the parent of the blue in order tio set the z-index propertie ... excuse my average english :)